# javascript: remove an EventListener and then add it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

The following code is the practical exercise of the event:

After the 3rd time of click, the Handler1 is removed, but I think when the user click the 4th time, the handler 1 should be added again. However, through several experiments, I found that if an event handler was removed by "removeEventListener", that listener can not be added back again. My question is that whether it is possible to add back a listener to an event again in Javascript?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
   <button id="btn1">Click me</button>
   <script>
      var count = 0;
      function countClick() {
         count++;
      }

      function handler1() {
         alert("Handler 1 has been triggered " + count + " times!");
      }

      function handler2() {
         alert("Handler 2 has been triggered " + count + " times!");
         if(count == 3) {
            btn1.removeEventListener("click", handler1);
         }
      }

      var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
      btn1.addEventListener("click", countClick);
      btn1.addEventListener("click", handler1);
      btn1.addEventListener("click", handler2);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"I found that if an event handler was removed by "removeEventListener", that listener can not be added back again"_ - I don't see you trying to add it back _again_ anywhere in your code. You add it once, when the script is executed at load time - and then what?

Comment: I works for me https://jsfiddle.net/tvr4r3d0/

Comment: you added it manually,,you have to add it again manually

Comment: It seems the code is working for what you have written. On the count == 3, the click handler doesn't invoke handler1 and only handler2 thereafter. To your question whether i can be added back or not, it certainly can be done. Take a look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/Lyh0zeo2/

Comment: Thank you all. Your answer clear my previous misunderstanding on JS. Now I know it can be added again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var count = 0;

 function countClick() {
   count++;
 }

 function handler1() {
   alert("Handler 1 has been triggered " + count + " times!");

   
 }

 function handler2() {
   alert("Handler 2 has been triggered " + count + " times!");
   if (count == 3) {
     btn1.removeEventListener("click", handler1);
   }
   
   if (count == 4) {
     btn1.addEventListener("click", handler1);
   }
 }

 var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
 btn1.addEventListener("click", countClick);
 btn1.addEventListener("click", handler1);
 btn1.addEventListener("click", handler2);
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="btn1">Click me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a beginner in javascript. I am learning in on Coursera. From your answer, I have a correct understanding on the click listener. Previously, I misunderstand that when I click on the botton, the webpage will load the entire script again. In fact, that is wrong. Your code will add the event listener again at the 4th click. Thank you again.